# Asp.net mvc deep validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I've created an asp.net application with following domain entities:

```
public class Person
{
  [Required]
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string address { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Item> ItemsPurchased { get; set;}
}

public class Item
{
  [Required]
  public string name { get; set; }
  public int price { get; set; }
}
```

with viewmodel

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
  public Person Entity { get; set; }
  public Item ItemPurchased { get; set; }
}
```

Now i have a form which asks to enter a person's details along with items purchased(if any)

```
Html.Label("Person Name")
Html.TextboxFor(model => model.Entity.name)
Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Entity.name)


Html.Label("Item Name")
Html.TextboxFor(model => model.ItemPurchased.name)
Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemPurchased.name)


Html.Label("Item Price")
Html.TextboxFor(model => model.ItemPurchased.Price)
Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemPurchased.Price)
```

And finally in controller i am going to add the item(if it is given by the user) to the collection.

```
if(!this.ModelState.IsValid)
{
  //Return the view with validation errors
}
```

**Main Problem**

Now if don't give the value of item name, it gives me an validation error "The name field is required". But i want to remove the validation on item object attributes for this form only. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a view model. View models are classes that are specifically designed to meet the requirements of the view. In this view you seem to have a requirement that the name is not required. So design a view model:

```
public class EditItemViewModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public class EditPersonViewModel
{
    public Person Entity { get; set; }
    public EditItemViewModel ItemPurchased { get; set; }
}
```

and you are good to go. The `name` will no longer be required for this form.

Also I would recommend you checking out [`AutoMapper`](http://automapper.org/) which could greatly simplify the mapping between your domain models and your view models.